# MME of $\theta^2x^2e^{-{\theta}x}$

Tags: estimation, moment-generating-functions

I need to find the Method Moment Estimator of parameter $\theta$ based on a random sample $X_1…X_n$ with the following pdf:

$f(x;\theta)=\theta^2x^2e^{-{\theta}x}$; $0<x$, zero otherwise; $0<\theta$

I am completely stuck on this. I know that the answer is supposed to be $\frac{2}{\bar{X}}$. I don't have the slightest idea how to arrive at that answer.

I am still new to this MME thing, but so far as I can tell, this pdf doesn't match any 'set' distribution, so I can't just plug in known moments. I have to calculate using integration. But how do I integrate this pdf?

If I plug it into WolframAlpha's integral calculator, it gives me the solution $\frac{e^{-x\theta}(-{\theta}x({\theta}x+2)-2)}{\theta}$. When I try to integrate by parts (I don't feel like typing out the entire process, because I did this in pen and paper), I get something that looks like $-\theta^2e^{-{\theta}x}(\theta^2x^2+2{\theta}x+2)$. Either way, this doesn't lead me anywhere close to the answer.

So any recommendations for how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, $E(X_1)=\frac12\theta$... and this is all there is to it, really. If need be, note that $f(\ ;\theta)$ is a well known distribution called gamma $(3,\theta)$.

Comment: I don't see how it is a gamma distribution. A gamma pdf with parameter $k=3$ would be $\frac{1}{{\Gamma}(3){\theta}^3}x^2e^{-{\theta}x}$

Comment: By the way, I was too hasty: *correctly normalized*, $f(\ ;\theta)$ would be the gamma PDF $(3,\theta)$. As written, $f(\ ;\theta)$ is not a PDF since it does not integrate to $1$. I suspect the formula you meant to write is $f(x;\theta)=\theta^2x\mathrm e^{-\theta x}\mathbf 1_{x\gt0}$.

Comment: Nope, I wrote the formula exactly as it is written on the assignment. It is $x^2$, not $x$.

Comment: So I did the work out using the formula you provided, and it gives me the correct answer. However, my assignment clearly has an $x^2$. It must be a typo.

Comment: And what about using your brain to see what YOU think of what was written on the assignment? The thing has not even the proper dimension...

Comment: And what about not being a jerk to people on a website that is designed for people to ask questions about math problems? Seriously, why would you feel the need to leave a snarky insult like that? Just to make you feel better about yourself because you are better at calculus than I am?

Comment: Was it a "thank you" that I just heard from you? You are welcome.